# How do I use a sans serif italic font for the greek letters in math mode?

Tags: equations, greek, mathastext

I'm using helvetica for math mode, but when I add a greek letter it apears in the default CMU font. How do I make it use helvetica for the greek letter too?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{helvet} \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{Abs}=\varepsilon lc \Leftrightarrow c=\frac{\mathrm{Abs}}{\varepsilon} \; (\text{Se }l=1\,\mathrm{cm}) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is this question different to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676817/problem-with-the-package-mathastext ?

Comment: The other one was not clear, as I added a command that only works inside math mode outside math mode. That command was useless as it didn't work anyway.

Comment: you should have edited that one rather than open a new, can you delete the old one now to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the package **newtxsf**. It's not exactly Helvetica, but in good matching with it. I use the scaled option because by default, the font is too small.

I also add the package **siunitx** so you don't have to manually write `1\,\mathrm{cm}`, but simply use `\qty{1}{\centi\meter}`.

Finally, I have replaced `\mathrm` with `\textup` (rather than `\text`, thanks to Barbara Beeton) from the **amsmath** package which you have already loaded.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{helvet} \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{newtxsf} % added

\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{siunitx} % added

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \textup{Abs}=\varepsilon lc \Leftrightarrow c=\frac{\textup{Abs}}{\varepsilon} \; (\textup{Se }l=\qty{1}{\centi\meter}) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Before:

[image]

With the new code (note that `\Leftrightarrow` is also adapted to the Helvetica font):

[image]

The new code without the *scaled* option:
[image]

Comment: You might want to consider `\textup` instead of just `\text`.  If such an expression appears within a theorem, where the text is italic, `\text` will simply follow the surrounding style.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your tip! You're completely right. I have edited the answer.